# java Change currency symbol to unicode hex in string

Tags: regex, unicode

I'd like to get the Unicode representation of a currency symbol in a string. How do i convert the currency symbols in the string below

```
The woman had a $500 handbag, but sold it for ₦13,000 to a Nigerian lady.
```

To:

```
The woman had a \ufdfc500 handbag, but sold it for \u20a613,000 to a Nigerian lady.
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think what you're looking for is String.ReplaceAll() ([API Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).)